# Команду из .bat файла перенести на python

Tags: python, bat, subprocess

Есть бат файл вида `"start C:\tt.exe --license "LBLqS8qM" --param2 --param3"`
Сам батник работает исправно, но хочу реализовать запуск этого кода на питоне.

Пробовал так

```
program = 'C:/tt.exe'
argument = '--license "LBLqS8qM" --param2 --param3'
s = subprocess.Popen([program, argument])
```

Запускается tt.exe, но параметры не учитываются.
Подскажите где ошибка?

Comment: Ну в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) каждый параметр даётся отдельным аргументом. См. примеры... кстати, а почему не просто `subprocess.run`?

Comment: как я понял popen открывает в другом потоке подпрограмму + ее можно потом килл. А мне собственно так и нужно. Я пробовал запускать с 1 параметром argument = '--license 'LBLqS8qm'', пробовал без -- с одной -..никакой реакции.

Answer (score 0):

**Используйте модуль [`os`](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html)**

```
import os

os.system('"start C:\tt.exe --license "LBLqS8qM" --param2 --param3"')
```

Если в батнике несколько строк, можно выполнить их через `&&`. Пример:

```
os.system('echo 1 && echo 2')
```

Comment: Еще можно из os.system сам bat'ник запустить :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте все аргументы передать как отдельные элементы списка в `Popen`:

```
program = 'C:/tt.exe'
process = subprocess.Popen([program, '--license', 'LBLqS8qM', '--param2', '--param3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(process.communicate())
```